# add default addres to account move

Tags: odoo-13

I have created for the following:

```
from odoo import models, fields


class AccountMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.move"

place_delivered = fields.Char(
    "Place of execution",
)
```

Now how do I set as default place of execution my own companies City?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you need to set your company city as a default value to the `place_delivered` field?

Answer (score 1):

You can access `city` using `company_id` field of the current logged user.

```
class AccountMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.move"

    def _get_user_company_city(self):
        return self.env.user.company_id.city

    place_delivered = fields.Char(
        "Place of execution",
        default=_get_user_company_city
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the following error:                                                                  NameError: name '_get_user_company_city' is not defined

Comment: Did you declare the method after the field?

Comment: pff right. thanks. works. now I only have to figure out how I limit it to showing up in invoice forms only :-)

Comment: 'pff right' referred to my mistake. Your help I accept in gratitude